# Are there any Saraswati sahasranaamas other than those from Skanda purana and Rudra Yamala Tantram?

Tags: tantra, saraswati, skanda-purana, saraswati-sahasranama

There are at least two Saraswati sahasranaamas, that I know, are available.

#1: From Skanda purana [1](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana50.html),[2](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/sarasvatisahasra.html)

At the request of Narada, Sanat Kumara Maharshi enumerated these sahastranaamas.

#2: [From Rudra Yamala Tantram](https://sathvishayam.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/sarasvati-sahasranamam-rudra-yamalam-eng.pdf)

The description on this source says the folowing

> The following is a rare Sahasranama Stotram (hymn containing 1008
> names) of Goddess Sarasvati from **Dasha Mahavidya Rahasyam** in **Rudra
> Yamala Tantram**. Lord Shiva, who gives this Sahasranama to Goddess
> Parvati.....

Are there any other such Saraswati sahasranaamas available?

Comment: The skanda Purana link here takes to Kamakoti webpage which says "Source: Avanti Khanda of Skanda Purana". But this sahasra Nama is not in Avanti khanda here https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425570.html. any other sources for this from Skanda Purana?

Comment: @Kanthri I added another one.

Comment: Thanks. This one has source as Sanatkumara samhita, which also I couldn't find in Skanda Purana. Wonder if at the end of sahasranama's they just add reference to a Purana.... Yet to find a skanda Purana version which has these chapters/sections. Anyway, thanks for these and I am diverting from your original question.

Comment: it is sahasra, not sahastra

Comment: Thanks @mar .....

Answer (score 2):

**1)** In **Rudrayamala Tantra** only, there is **Sharada Sahastranaam Stotram**, now if you consider Saraswati and Sharada as same, you can go ahead because many a times, Sharada Devi is said to be a different Shakti than Saraswati Devi, although they both are Adhishtatri Devi of Knowledge.
I am sharing the link of Sharada Sahastranaam Stotram below:

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/shAradAsahasranAmastotra.html

**2)** In **Skand Puran**, there is **Vagmati Sahasranam Stotram**, link is below:

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/vAgmatisahasranAmastotram.html

**3)** In **Bhavishyottar Puran**, there is **Vagvadini Sahasranam Stotram**, link is below:

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/vAgvAdinIsahasranAmastotoram.html

Thank you.